# Agregar campo a una vista por medio de migración

Tags: laravel, postgresql

Tengo un sistema que se encuentra en producción realizado en Laravel y Postgress y una de las migraciones crea una vista de la siguiente manera:

```
 $statement = "CREATE VIEW property_view AS SELECT property.id as property_id, ";

 foreach($this->sections as $section) {
            $statement = array_reduce($section->getFillable(), function($statement, $field) 
 use ($section) {
                return $statement .= "{$section->getTable()}.{$field}, ";
            }, $statement);
        }

        return rtrim($statement, ", ");
```

Esto funciona muy bien, pero ahora a una de las tablas se le agregó un campo nuevo, por lo que al estar en produccion no puedo modificar la migracion anterior y cree una nueva y ahi
intenté varias formas agregar este campo pero sin exito:

```
 DB::statement("ALTER VIEW property_view ADD COLUMN apn_number VARCHAR");
```

Vale recordar que es postgress

Answer (score 2, accepted):

puedes hacer lo siguiente en la nueva migración:

1. Renombrar la vista vieja
2. Crear la vista nueva con todos los campos (incluyendo el nuevo)

Prueba que todo funcione como debe ser y finalmente

3. Eliminar la vista vieja.

Las vistas no almacenan datos, consultas con las que puedes operar como tablas de solo lectura.